# Print all OpenGL parameters

Tags: opengl

There is [glGet](https://docs.gl/es2/glGet) which prints a property value.

Is there a function that retrieves all the properties and their value?

Comment: There isn't. Since glGet doesn't allocate memory for you, you'd still have to reserve the correct memory type and size before that.